# How to retrieve only the number of seats for all the subscriptions of my customers? (Google Workplace Reseller)

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-reseller-api

I am using the following JS code to retrieve seats details for all the subscriptions of my customers.

```js
gapi.client.reseller.subscriptions.list()
  .then(function(response) {
    // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
    console.log("Response", response);
  },
  function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
```

However, it's returning all of their other information as well. How can I customize it so that it only returns the number of seats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google APIs has a standard parameter called `fields` that allows you select which fields are included in the response ([see documentation on Docs API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/fields-parameter)).

In Google API Client Library for JavaScript (aka `gapi`) you can simply add the parameters in an object when making a request. In your case this should work:

```js
gapi.client.reseller.subscriptions.list({
  fields: [
    'nextPageToken',
    'subscriptions/subscriptionId',
    'subscriptions/seats/numberOfSeats',
  ].join(',')
})
```

It's important to keep all fields that you need including control fields like `nextPageToken`. [You can read more about the format used here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/fields-parameter#formatting_rules_for_the_fields_parameter).